# Intersecting keys in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to write a type-safe utility function for comparison of properties of 2 given objects in Typescript 4.0. My initial attempt is as following:

```js
export function propsAreEqual<O extends object, T extends O, S extends O>(first: T, second: S, props: (keyof O)[]) {
    return props.every(prop => first[prop] === second[prop])
}
```

However, I get a compile error TS2367 with this approach, which states that:
`This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T[keyof O]' and 'S[keyof O]' have no overlap.`

That error seems counter-intuitive to me. If both `T` and `S` extend object of type `O` then shouldn't they both necessarily contain all keys of type `O`? I would greatly appreciate if anyone could clarify what am I missing here and if there is a more sound approach to what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is not incorrect, extending `O` just means extends `object`, and in turn this means you could have `T = { a: number }` and `O = { a: string }` ([ex](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzFCMAZwEEpgBRARyQEMAbAHgHk5QZgUATIuCAIwBWwDABo4AFTYgO3Xs3EBlabJ5xmAPgAUCTFCIwAXJPFEROLscXj8hIsa0BrYAE8ICdQEoA2gF1PcADeAFBwYXDkMEhQuLbEAHTAAG7AUC5acXAAvBqIegbecb7ZWVlwZmgWhQRg-sEAvsHB9MDwtNlBoXwowMYAjKJdMADuEMYATIP1ANxNLfD8HSFhOL1wAER964NhMAAW5GsAzFOzwZUoRBAt8fQQAOYZNaTk1HT0WrTi-OLe66vrfyeaZwAD0oLgSQYmC4cDQDHoQA)). The key is the same, but there is no overlap between `T[keyof O]` and `O[keyof O]`. There could be overlap, but when dealing with TS expects to be able to prove the function is correct for any valid instantiation of the type parameter, and as we see here there can be cases where this function is not valid.

You could have several approaches to defining this function you could use a single type parameter for the first object, and define the second object as a `Pick` or the passed in properties.

```
function propsAreEqual<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(first: T, second: Pick<T, K>, props: K[]) {
    return props.every(prop => first[prop] === second[prop])
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE52QZwIKoKYCiAjiAIYA2APACqJ4AeUeYAJponAEYBWe0ANIgDSdRszaIA1ngCecYImoA+ABTAYqTFABciwZj4IWugAowIkmoKFLBaDJl1CA2gF0AlIgDeAKET-EfCgQVCR7LAA6PAA3PFQZFXDEAF4lRHVNKGdw1xTk5MQDCCNs9GQPHwBfHx9yPChEUhTvPw4wPF0ARn5WqAB3OF0AJh7KgG4auobOZt9-BA7Ebt6AC3xFgGZRiZ9isEw4OojyOABzRLKcfGIychVSQU5BZwAiBZePdwmAem-EAnoEDwmHY4TiUBkiAgKz4knYknMkkQMCQuwQByOJ3O4SuhBIFHugjmbUWy38UDWeE2o2eb3aH3cXyAA)

This version will ensure that T[K] is the same type for both parameters. The disadvantage of this version is that if you try to pass in  an object literal as the second parameter, excess property checks will kick in. Also another disadvantage is that intellisense will suggest all properties of `T` in the third parameter, and if the property is not common, you will get an error on the second parameter.

Personally I would prefer an option that sacrifices full type checking in the function in return for fixing the two problems above. This would be this version:

```
function propsAreEqual<T extends object,  S extends Pick<T, K>,  K extends keyof T & keyof S>(first: T, second: S, props: K[]) {
    return props.every(prop => first[prop] === (second as Pick<T, K>)[prop])
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE52QZwIKoKYCiAjiAIYA2APACqJ4AeUeYAJponAEYBWe0ANIkQBlOo2ZtEABRgQA1jUEBpAHyDESsU1bs5eAJ5xgiWgDJEew8eEqAFMBipMUAFwnBmPghZvhgtBiYbkoA2gC6AJSIAN4AUEJC+FAgqEgBWAB0eABueKj6tumIALwqiA5OUCHpYSXFxYi2nhDeiKTsMvKKGioR1ejIkbEAvrGx5HhQbSUx8RxgeG4AjPxzUADucG4ATKvDANxjE1OcM3FCCIuIK2sAFvhXAMx7h7EtYJhwExnkcADmhQGOHwxDI5FspEEnEEIQARJdYZEIod3p9vr8AelgYQSBQIVCYfCFrDBLCoPc8HhERFkYgAPR0uiodCoRBjBmIADycjeCDReB+-0BgVwOLB+NmFwWy1WQnJDzczxGhIRSP2QA)

Comment: I'm glad to see I got the reason for the error basically right. :-) Nice solution! I don't think I realized type parameters could have circular references like that. Wow, that's cool.

Comment: Indeed, @t-j-crowder, you got that one right. Shame to see your answer deleted though :/ And @titian-cernicova-dragomir's final solution appears to be doing exactly what I was looking for, i.e. inferring array type from the object types. "_extending `O` just means extends `object`_" Oh, ok, that makes it more clear. Once again I had wrong assumptions about how TS infers types...

Comment: @arslancharyev31 - Very kind. :-) But I didn't think my answer added any value given Titian's. I can undelete it if you prefer, but the above covers the points well. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

When you infer a type parameter, Typescript wants to infer it from just one of the arguments; so the signature `propsAreEqual<T>(a: T, b: T, props: (keyof T)[])` doesn't work because Typescript infers `T` from the type of the first argument and then doesn't try to loosen it when it finds that the second argument isn't assignable to that type.

Solution: use a generic type which will be inferred from `props` instead of from `a` or `b`.

```
function propsAreEqual<K extends PropertyKey>(a: Record<K, unknown>, b: Record<K, unknown>, props: K[]) {
    return props.every(prop => a[prop] === b[prop]);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE52QZwIKoKYCiAjiAIYA2APANKJ4AeUeYAJpogArrJ6pQCe1PPwB8AClIAuRACU8EOKhY0ANInABrMHADuYEWoBG0uQqWr1YLbv1q0GTNOoBtALoBKRAG8AUIkT4UCCoSPZYAHR4AG68-GJhiAC8IoikzmGuSYmJiIbp3B4A3D4Avj4+5HhQqUnefogIeNIAjCr1UDpw0gBMbSXFFVW5tb7+jS1t-lAAFvhNiADMfQMA9CuI2nSo6Kg+YTj4xGTkEkZqzgBEjRdF5WtbO9JhvAKIAOQzc2+IMOwAtr9MDAwABzH5IAQ8bzjDYgP6GXhqDpdWHw3hlfa4QgkCinXLnC6fPB4G7uYpAA)

Comment: That is a really interesting solution as well, but it seems to be functionally equivalent to the example provided by @t-j-crowder, albeit written more succinctly. The question I had is whether it is possible to make TS infer the type of `props` parameter from the provided objects instead since it should possible in principle.

Comment: It is not equivalent to either of the examples in T.J. Crowder's answer. Note that his first example does not meet the requirements, and his second example has three type parameters and a type assertion.

Comment: I meant that fundamentally they both use the given array for type inference and then validate the provided objects, isn't it? I was just wondering if it is possible to do it the other way around, i.e. have TS infer the common properties of 2 types and then use it to validate the given array. This would be functionally different since it would also enable code completion.

Comment: I see what you mean about code completion, but I think the problem is that Typescript infers a type parameter from just one argument, not the common properties of two, and if you have two different type parameters for the two arguments (to allow them to be different), then you'll get the (logically incorrect) error about the condition always being false. I can't say for certain that there isn't a workaround, but intuitively it seems unlikely to me.